# How to create a coordinate and update latest position of Android Beacon Library?

Tags: java, android

I have a trouble, I don't know how to display positioning system.
Assume, I known beacon location, likes maps present it in the indoor environment, how can I do? Current I already use an array depositary beacon data(UUID, Major, Minor, RSSI). How to use this information to create a 2D positioning coordinates on Android?